# Bulk insert or update if 2 column of table already exists MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a relation table with no primary key:

```
ticket_id | type | value | code
```

i want to do insert and update into this table with bulk method, the condition to update is if the `ticket_id` and `code` are injected with duplicate data, then it will update the type or value record. How can i achieve this?

for example  i will be receiving insert data like this:

```
    [
      {
         "ticket_id":"1",
         "type":"name",
         "value":"Ben",
         "code":"person_name"
      },
      {
         "ticket_id":"1",
         "type":"phone",
         "value":"0812",
         "code":"person_phone"
      },
      {
         "ticket_id":"1",
         "type":"mail",
         "value":"ben@yours.com",
         "code":"person_mail"
      },
      {
         "ticket_id":"2",
         "type":"name",
         "value":"Jesse",
         "code":"person_name"
      },
      {
         "ticket_id":"2",
         "type":"phone",
         "value":"8272",
         "code":"person_phone"
      },
      {
         "ticket_id":"2",
         "type":"mail",
         "value":"jesse@mine.com",
         "code":"person_mail"
      }
   ]
```

then the update data:

```
   [
      {
         "ticket_id":"1",
         "type":"name",
         "value":"Joe",
         "code":"person_name"
      },
      {
         "ticket_id":"1",
         "type":"phone",
         "value":"9810",
         "code":"person_phone"
      },
      {
         "ticket_id":"1",
         "type":"mail",
         "value":"joe@mine.com",
         "code":"person_mail"
      },
      {
         "ticket_id":"2",
         "type":"name",
         "value":"Rose",
         "code":"person_name"
      },
      {
         "ticket_id":"2",
         "type":"phone",
         "value":"0992",
         "code":"person_phone"
      },
      {
         "ticket_id":"2",
         "type":"mail",
         "value":"rose@yours.com",
         "code":"person_mail"
      }
   ]
```

Comment: `INSERT....... On Duplicate UPDATE`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `insert ... on duplicate key` syntax - as commented by RiggsFolly:

```
insert into mytable (ticket_id, type, value, code)
values(:ticket_id, :type, :value, :code)
on duplicate key update type = values(type), value = values(value)
```

For this to work, you need a unique constraint on `(ticket_id, code)`.